# Automapper forsourcemember ignore not working

Tags: c#, automapper

I am pulling from an entity object and trying to map to a model.  Here is my class information:

// entity class was auto-generated

```
**public partial class CategoryType
    {
        public CategoryType()
        {
            this.OutgoingCategories = new HashSet<OutgoingCategory>();
        }

        public int CategoryTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OutgoingCategory> OutgoingCategories { get; set; }
    }**


public class CategoryTypeModel  

{

public int CategoryTypeID { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public string Icon { get; set; }

}
```

My mapper looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryType, CategoryTypeModel>().ForSourceMember(a => a.OutgoingCategories, o => o.Ignore());
```

When I go to get the mapped list:

```
Mapper.Map  <List<CategoryType>, List<CategoryTypeModel>>(dbo.CategoryTypes.ToList());
```

I get the error:

Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

I'm new to using Automapper, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I said I was new to Automapper.  So.... I guess it would help to call this in my Global.asax:

```
AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
```

That solved the problem.